# Coin cell batteries that are 1V or lower?

Tags: batteries, coin-cell

Does anyone if there are any coin cell batteries that are 1V or lower? I did a Google search and I checked on websites like Mouser, Digikey and find that the smallest voltage is 1.4 or 1.5V

Comment: Sounds like an XY question. Why do you need this? Cell voltages are limited by their chemistry and there are only so many chemistries available. You typically do not go out hunting for a cell voltage. The cell voltage is usually already defined for you due to other constraints determining the battery type and you must build your circuit to match.

Comment: Cadmium anode, mercuric oxide (and water) cathode, and potassium hydroxide as the electrolyte. This is almost exactly what you want. It's 0.95 V and they used to make them, too. Though, I admit, I don't know if they ever made them as a coin cell. But the chemistry is right and the technology is mature.

Comment: How about -1.4 volts or 0 volts?

Comment: You might be looking for a Weston cell (1.018V) or a Daniell cell (1.1V). Don't know of any in coin cell form factor though.

Comment: @DKNguyen: The process node I am using natively supports ~0.8V (+/-0.2V) supply which is powered using a regular bench supply. However, the chip also contains special circuits that need to operate when the chip is powered off and hence we rely on a battery supply. Since low-leakage coin-cell batteries like the SR44SW only go as low as 1.5 V, we are having to build extra circuitry to *not* damage the transistor. Since we do have the freedom to pick a battery, I just wanted to pick a low voltage battery if it's available. Hope this clarifies.

Comment: @SharathRaju It does clarify. Thanks. But what voltage range can it tolerate since batteries start off at a higher voltage that decreases as the battery drains. If either limit exceeds your battery then you may not be able to run off a 0.8V nominal battery directly anyways.

Comment: @DKNguyen. The safe voltage range for the transistors are 0.6-1.0 V
If you see the the SR44SW battery discharge characteristic on Page 22, the battery starts off at 1.6 V but stays flat at ~1.55 V before losing charge..In fact, Seiko mentions stable power voltage as one of the features. In my case, I was hoping for a nominal voltage of 1 V, and even if the battery loses charge by a few 100 mV it shouldn't matter.  Ref: https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/360/MicroBattery_catalogue_E_2018_forWeb-1358329.pdf